# Allow authors to create article image

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, functions, images, uploads

I want to allow contributors to upload images while creating posts.  But the catch is, I am building the post display pages out of my own custom PHP.

Every article written will follow the same template:

```
ImageOfArticle
UserAvitar
Name
Content
Footer
```

Is there a way to allow them to upload an image in the default post editor, and to be able to access that somewhere with PHP, and display that in  the 'ImageOfArticle'?

Answer (score 0):

There is the built in [post thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails). Wordpress will keep track of it and you can use `the_post_thumbnail` to display wherever needed.

Comment: This is a much better solution than what I had. 

however, I kinda want to have two images, is there any functionality here?

Comment: By two images do you mean that you want two images specific to each post or the thumbnail and the author avatar?

Comment: As in, assume an array of thumbnails.  

that way I can access different thumbnails.  

thumbs[0], thumbs[1] etc.

Comment: I would look into [custom fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields). You could store the address of each additional image in the custom field.